# What do you say when someone interrupts you?

Tags: sentence-choice

Imagine that you are talking about something with your friend. Then your friend interrupts you. You still want to talk. What do you say to let him or her know that you want to keep talking?

1. "Let me finish my sentence."
2. "Let me talk."
3. "Let me finish my word."
4. "Let me finish."

Comment: This is a matter of etiquette and not language, and what you say hugely varies according to how polite you want to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples sound a bit direct and rude, maybe angry. Your #3 is just wrong because a word is too short to want to finish.

When people interrupt me, I give them the benefit of the doubt, that they weren't aware they were interrupting, and might have thought I was finished speaking. So I say,

"*I'm sorry, I wasn't finished speaking.*"

Even if they are interrupting, this tells them you want to continue speaking. If it's clear they're interrupting because I was in the middle of a sentence, rather than *tell* them to let me continue, I *ask them permission* to continue:

"*Would you mind if I finished what I was saying?*"

You can also use these when someone is interrupting in order to be disrespectful or hostile. By responding politely *and firmly*, you'll look better than them.

Answer (score 1):

Even if they have been rude by interrupting you, it is best to be polite in return, so "Please let me finish" is probably the best thing to say. Or possibly "Please let me talk". The other two are unlikely to be said by a native BrE speaker.